# Grub2 won't install on fresh Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server installation

Tags: installation, hardware-raid, ubuntu-12.04, grub2

I have a hardware RAID 1 which seems to be recognized find by the Ubuntu installer.  I choose the "Entire Disk - Guided" partition strategy and accept the defaults, writing them to disk.  When it comes to choosing where to put Grub2, however, everything I try fails.  Any advice would be awesome.

Comment: Drop to shell and extend your question with errors from the ``/var/log/syslog``.

Comment: Does your server happen to have something like a FC (Fibre Channel) card installed so your server sees some additional LUNs / drives there? If that's the case, Debian/Ubuntu installer can sometimes get confused and try to install GRUB to those SAN drives instead of the drives you originally planned...

Comment: No, it has 2 x 160gb and 2 x 320gb.  Each pair is in a hardware RAID 1.  I am trying to install on the 160gb pair, leaving the 320gb pair to format and mount after installation.

Comment: @RomanB. how do I drop to shell during install?

Comment: In Debian, there is Expert Install, there you can drop to shell. This might be in Ubuntu too.

Comment: Ok thanks.. I'm trying just single disk install atm.. RAID just isn't happening.

Comment: I'm trying to do a similar thing with RAID 0. I haven't been successful yet, but I believe you'll have to install grub2 manually. I managed to get my Ubuntu installation to "succeed" by following steps here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB2, but I can't boot...

Comment: @LukeGT Thanks for posting.  Let me know how you go.  I ran out of time so I'm now running something fairly critical on a single disk :(  I would love to get it on the RAID if possible.  Cheers